# Editable PDF export for Client with Affinity (Do not want to use Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, affinity-designer, affinity-publisher

I am learning Designing and looking in affinity designer. I want to create simple editable PDF (only name and few words may be editable) by client.

As I understood AFfinity does not provide way to create editable PDF.

My question - is there a way with Affinity (Photo, Deisgner or Publisher) where I can design everything using the software and let customer edit/ add very small details like name etc?

Thanks

Comment: You have already got an answer, but there's a trap. Your client must have all fonts that are used in editable parts. You have generally no right to include nor give them except in case they are explicitly licensed as freely distributable. See this for more details https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2439825

Comment: @user287001 I wish that was applicable :) unfortunately fillable form in Adobe (be it interactive pdf from InDesign or one made in Acrobat) will use minion pro (or this is what happening to me)

Answer (score 1):

As for now there is no way to create interactive/form fields pdf's in Affinity.
I would advise to use third party software (if you would like to avoid adobe you could use pdfFormCreatingApp)

Comment: I would love to but not sure how much graphic design I can create with other apps.

Comment: @KaushikRay pdf form creating programs work on pre-made pdfs. So you can create bare bone one in Designer and then add/change fields to be fillable/ changed.

Answer (score -3):

**Affinity Activity Diagram:**

A method for sorting and making sense out of data you collected in research phase to identify common themes and discover unseen connections.

In simple words, it means ***writing your finding on sticky notes and group them in sensible manner.***

**Steps to Create Work Activity Affinity Diagram:**

- Write your findings on sticky notes.
- Paste them on white board into groups
- Try to find common themes between them.
- Create Groups and Sub-Groups(re-arrange).
- Give points and rating to most important ideas.

Using [this](https://balsamiq.cloud/) could design affinity and it allow to share, comment/edit.

Check below sample affinity diagram for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi Naveen. I don't think this answers the question unfortunately. The OP is looking for a way to use Affinity software to design a PDF which his customer can edit, i.e. a PDF with editable text fields.